# A way to print the name of the instance

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a class Person:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

In the Main class, I display the particulars of all the instances of this class (persons):

```
    List<Person> itemsToPermute = new List<Person>();
    Person a = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 12 };
    Person b = new Person { Name = "Clara", Age = 57 };
    Person c = new Person { Name = "Martha", Age = 81 };
    Person d = new Person { Name = "Leon", Age = 23 };
    Person e = new Person { Name = "Rina", Age = 48 };

    itemsToPermute.Add(a);
    itemsToPermute.Add(b);
    itemsToPermute.Add(c);
    itemsToPermute.Add(d);
    itemsToPermute.Add(e);
    private static void Display(string prompt, List<Person> allPersons)
    {
        foreach (Person currentPerson in allPersons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentPerson.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The output is:
Person: John 12
Person: Clara 57
...
and so on.
I would like to be able to also show the instance name:
Person: a John 12
Is there a way to retrieve the a (the instance name)?
The whole purpose of this question is to learn whether there is a way in C# to programmatically find out the name of the instance of the class.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect the name "person1" to come from? It doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

Comment: What happens if you have `var person1 = new Person {...}; var samePerson = person1;`? Should the `ToString()` print "person1" or "samePerson"? The class knows nothing about the names of the variables of its instances.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but I think if you want to get variable name as string, you have a problem with your code architecture or some algorithm that requires it. Can you maybe give us a context and a goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @JarekDanielak Wanting to get the name of the variable isn't always a bad thing. That's what `nameof` is for. It's used all the time when throwing ArgumentExceptions, for example.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I am sorry. My example contained in the beginning the instances names person1, person2, ...,  person5. This caused a misunderstanding, so I changed the instances names to a, b, c, d and e respectively. My question is whether it is possible to programmatically retrieve these instances names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance doesn't have a name. A *variable* has a name, but an object doesn't "know" which variables refer to it, and there could be multiple of them. For example:

```cs
Person person1 = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 12 };
Person person2 = person1;
```

Now both the values of both `person1` and `person2` refer to the same object - what would you expect the name to be?

Basically, if you want to keep some extra data along with the object, you need to do so explicitly, just like you have done for `Name` and `Age`.

Comment: in this case, I would wish to retrieve a list of variables names of the instances (all the variables names that reference the respective object).

Comment: @user2102327: That facility basically doesn't exist - an object doesn't know about variables that might refer to it, any more than a house knows every address book that might contain the address of the house.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood this from your answer, therefore I marked it as answer. I just replied to your question: what would you expect the name to be?

Answer (score 2):

I would use and for-loop for the iteration over all elements. Then you have the instance number directly.

Example:

```
class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " " + Age;
        }
    }

    private static void Display(List<Person> allPerson)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allPerson.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person{i} "+allPerson[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

You also may change the **{i}** to **{i+1}** if you want to start the person number by 1

---

### if you want to detect every thing automatically (ClassName, and current index in List)

```
foreach (Person currentPerson in allPerson)
        {
            int currentIndex = allPerson.IndexOf(currentPerson);
            Console.WriteLine($"{currentPerson.GetType().Name}: {currentPerson.GetType().Name}{currentIndex+1} {currentPerson}");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the point! I might name the instances a,b, c, d, e. The question is how to get the instance names: (a, b, c, d, e) respectively.

Comment: So you want the name of a where a is a object of type Person?


e.g.
Person a = new Person(....);

then I would use nameof(a)

Comment: I want to discover the name a programatically. This is the purpose of my question.

Comment: Okay let me summarize what I have understood. You have a Model (called Person) and want to shall all Persons using a identifier like: 'Person1' and then print out the name and the age? Is this correct?

Comment: I added a second example. Hope this one helps. If not just leave a comment here

Comment: You did not get the purpose of the question. As I mentioned before, this is only an example. What I would like to know is whether there is a way in C# to programmatically discover the name of the instance. I did not mean to be rude. I apologise. I probably did not express the question clearly. My intention is only to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210941/discussion-between-patrickdevs-and-user2102327).